# How do I structure an AWS CDK application to be able to import from a python package in the same root directory?

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I have a project directory that looks like,

```
.
├── infrastructure
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── stacks
│   ├── batch
│       └── long_running
│           ├── Dockerfile
│           ├── app.py
│   └── functions
│       └── lambda1
│           ├── Dockerfile
│           ├── app.py
│           └── requirements.txt
├── pyproject.toml
└── src
    ├── myprogram
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── core.py
```

Inside my `lambda1` function, I want to import code from `myprogram.core`; for example,

*infrastructure/functions/lambda1/app.py*

```
from myprogram.core import SomeClass

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    foo = SomeClass()
    ...
```

How do I make `myprogram` available so that I can import it into my infrastructure application?

Answer (score 1):

You can put your modules into:

1. Zip code bundle
2. Layers
3. Docker image
4. Attached persistent filesystem.

The latter is an edge case usage (for code larger than 10G), so I'm not gonna focus on that.

Layers are the easiest option. You create a `FileAsset` out of your `src/myprogram` directory, make a `LayerVersion` construct with this asset, and attach it to your lambda.

It will get mounted at `/opt` within the lambda runtime container. Lambda Python runtime is set up to import from `/opt/python`, so make sure your asset folder structure starts with `python` (e.g. `/src/myprogram/python/`).

Layers only work if your lambda code is provided inline or in a zip archive.

Docker images are the next easiest option. You'll have to build your modules code and lambda code into different layers, using one as a base for another. If you want to do it in a single Dockerfile, you'll need to put it somewhere above both folders. Alternatively, you can build the two images in two steps, in this case you can use two different Dockerfiles.

Normally, putting both folders into a single zip archive would be another easy thing. Unfortunately, CDK cannot easily combine multiple directories for a single asset. There is a feature request for that tracked [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/984). Until it's implemented properly, you'll to put both folders together, so they could end up in a single asset.

If you are going to reuse module code for multiple lambdas, use the layers (one flavor or another).